# Is there a way to make Happstack recompile and auto-reload?

Tags: haskell, happstack

Currently, when building with happstack, I have to recompile my project, relaunch my `.exe` binary (in windows) every time I make a change to my template or source code.

Is there some tools that can automate this, like what Yesod or Snap has?

P.S.: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/happstack/issues/detail?id=220) is my issue about this on happstack bug tracker.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to do this is with [happstack-plugins](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-plugins); there's some old documentation [in this blog post](http://happstack.blogspot.com/2010/10/recompile-your-haskell-based-templates.html). This package could use some love though, in particular it calls ghc directly without talking to cabal, so getting it to work with cabal-dev requires setting GHC_PACKAGE_PATH manually and if you're using cabal properties like hs-source-dirs or extensions you have to configure plugins to pass the right flags to ghc...

Another option if you're on Linux is to install inotify-tools and write a make task like [this one](https://github.com/dag/kibr/blob/master/Makefile#L34).

Comment: Thanks, but I am using windows. Also, cabal-dev is PITA to install, why can't we make do without it? Snap does it somehow.

Comment: Well, the maintainer of Happstack doesn't use cabal-dev himself, and happstack-plugins works *better* without it. So sure, there's no hard requirement on cabal-dev; I just use it myself. Unfortunately I know little about Windows, not sure how much help I can be there.